How to limit the build ram usage of a vite/node project?
I have a vite-react project which build in my pc (8 core/16 GB ram) just fine. But when I try to build in the production server (4 core/ 8 GB ram) the build fails. I have optimized the code but I have no idea to check the solution for the production server as it is running in a different server (4 core/ 16 GB ram).
Is there any way to check whether my build in my pc without actually changing the hardwires.
I am using VS Code as my code editor. An extension for it would be a great suggestion.
I am expecting a VS code extension for build the project with a feature to limit ram usage. Or a way to build the project with limited ram usage.

Does this answer your question?
